# Ubuntu 14.04 logs user out at random intervals

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, logout

I recently did and update and dist upgrade. I am getting logged out at indeterminable moments (not very frequently, however). I cannot find any information on this bug. I am using Ubuntu at work and would greatly appreciate some help to resolve this as soon as possible.

I am using Gnome. I have an Nvidia Geforce 740M card. Drivers are proprietary I think.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1587]
    Kernel driver in use: i915 
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] [10de:0fdf] (rev ff)
```

Update - including some debug information:

auth.log:

```
Aug 18 08:17:01 dominic-K56CB CRON[14090]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 18 08:17:01 dominic-K56CB CRON[14090]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 18 07:25:27 dominic-K56CB polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:c4 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action com.ubuntu.softwareproperties.applychanges for system-bus-name::1.127 [/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab 2 --toplevel 25165832] (owned by unix-user:dominic)
Aug 18 08:32:49 dominic-K56CB polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c4 (system bus name :1.104, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_ZA.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Aug 18 08:32:49 dominic-K56CB su[12430]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Aug 18 08:32:49 dominic-K56CB sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 18 08:32:49 dominic-K56CB su[13681]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Aug 18 08:32:49 dominic-K56CB sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 18 08:32:49 dominic-K56CB gdm-password][4280]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user dominic
Aug 18 08:32:49 dominic-K56CB dbus[382]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.9" (uid=0 pid=1101 comm="gdm ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.132" (uid=0 pid=14543 comm="/usr/lib/gdm/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gn")
Aug 18 08:32:50 dominic-K56CB gdm-launch-environment][14558]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Aug 18 08:32:50 dominic-K56CB systemd-logind[639]: Removed session c4.
Aug 18 08:32:50 dominic-K56CB systemd-logind[639]: New session c5 of user gdm.
Aug 18 08:32:50 dominic-K56CB systemd-logind[639]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/117/X11-display.
Aug 18 08:32:50 dominic-K56CB gdm-launch-environment][14558]: pam_ck_connector(gdm-launch-environment:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Aug 18 08:32:54 dominic-K56CB polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c5 (system bus name :1.144 [gnome-shell --mode=gdm], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_ZA.UTF-8)
Aug 18 08:33:12 dominic-K56CB systemd-logind[639]: Failed to issue method call: Unknown unit: autovt@tty6.service
```

I couldn't find anything that stood out in these others:

```
     adm        899706 Aug 18 08:34 kern.log
     utmp       201984 Aug 18 08:35 wtmp
     root        32586 Aug 18 08:35 Xorg.0.log
     adm        200727 Aug 18 08:39 syslog
```

Edit: I've added the output from .xsession-errors:

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: unity-settings-daemon main process ended, respawning
init: unity-settings-daemon main process (5334) terminated with status 1
init: unity-panel-service main process (2265) terminated with status 1
init: indicator-bluetooth main process (2373) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-power main process (2378) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-datetime main process (2382) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-printers main process (2387) terminated with status 1
init: indicator-session main process (2411) killed by TERM signal
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2260) terminated with status 1
init: indicator-application main process (2423) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
Xsession: X session started for dominic at Mon Feb  2 14:52:16 SAST 2015
localuser:dominic being added to access control list
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-yh44XH
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=2261
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-yh44XH
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-yh44XH/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-yh44XH
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-yh44XH/gpg:0:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-yh44XH/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-yh44XH
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-yh44XH/gpg:0:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-yh44XH/ssh

(unity-settings-daemon:2260): AccountsService-WARNING **: SetInputSources call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Accounts.Error.PermissionDenied: Not authorized

(unity-settings-daemon:2260): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile auth
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp

** (process:2336): WARNING **: killswitch.vala:103: Can't open /dev/rfkill for use as a killswitch backend: Permission denied

** (process:2336): CRITICAL **: bluez.vala:104: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdapter: No such adapter
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
process 2331: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1263.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
initctl: UPSTART_SESSION isn't set in the environment. Unable to locate the Upstart instance.
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl

** (process:2345): CRITICAL **: volume_control_set_volume_internal: assertion '_tmp1_ == PA_CONTEXT_READY' failed

** (process:2345): CRITICAL **: file /build/buildd/indicator-sound-12.10.2+14.04.20140401/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/volume-control.c: line 1775: uncaught error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface (g-dbus-error-quark, 16)
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
Compiz (opengl) - Info: GLX_EXT_buffer_age is supported
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/dominic/.compiz/session/107e083f2245eea23f142288154425169700000021150001"
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct

(zeitgeist-datahub:2554): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(zeitgeist-datahub:2554): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(unity-settings-daemon:2260): media-keys-plugin-WARNING **: Unable to get default sink
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 5038 requests (5038 known processed) with 10 events remaining.
blueman-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Loading configuration plugins
blueman-applet version 1.23 starting
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
gtk-window-decorator: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.0.
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : Default
Xsession: X session started for dominic at Mon Feb  2 15:01:37 SAST 2015
localuser:dominic being added to access control list
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
libGL error: failed to open drm device: Permission denied
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
gnome-session-is-accelerated: llvmpipe detected.
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=2375

** (unity-settings-daemon:2374): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg/gpg:0:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg/gpg:0:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-2Z0Stg/ssh

(gnome-settings-daemon:2355): media-keys-plugin-WARNING **: Grab failed for some keys, another application may already have access the them.

(gnome-settings-daemon:2355): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to create device: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device auth
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core

(gnome-settings-daemon:2355): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file '/var/lib/gdm/.local/share/icc/edid-cfb289a378dfeb0dad9043dbbe10f43f.icc': Permission denied
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp

(gnome-settings-daemon:2355): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile auth

(gnome-settings-daemon:2355): AccountsService-WARNING **: SetInputSources call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Accounts.Error.PermissionDenied: Not authorized
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
process 2441: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1263.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

** (process:2442): WARNING **: killswitch.vala:103: Can't open /dev/rfkill for use as a killswitch backend: Permission denied

** (process:2442): CRITICAL **: bluez.vala:104: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdapter: No such adapter

** (process:2454): CRITICAL **: volume_control_set_volume_internal: assertion '_tmp1_ == PA_CONTEXT_READY' failed

** (process:2454): CRITICAL **: file /build/buildd/indicator-sound-12.10.2+14.04.20140401/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/volume-control.c: line 1775: uncaught error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface (g-dbus-error-quark, 16)
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
initctl: UPSTART_SESSION isn't set in the environment. Unable to locate the Upstart instance.
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
libGL error: failed to open drm device: Permission denied
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/dominic/.compiz/session/10e0153760db08b4cd142288210073067700000022670001"
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Warn: Attempted to restack relative to 0x2a00025 which is not a child of the root window or a window compiz owns

(zeitgeist-datahub:2667): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(zeitgeist-datahub:2667): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(gnome-settings-daemon:2355): media-keys-plugin-WARNING **: Unable to get default sink
XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":0"
blueman-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
      after 9555 requests (9555 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Loading configuration plugins
blueman-applet version 1.23 starting
Stale PID, overwriting
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
Using gconf config backend
gtk-window-decorator: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.0.
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : Default
```

Comment: Once you login again, open a terminal window with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, then type `ls -rlt /var/log`. The last several files listed may contain information about what just happened, near the end of the files.

Comment: @waltinator I've updated the question.  Noted the following from auth.log: Operator of unix-session:c4 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action com.ubuntu.softwareproperties.applychanges for system-bus-name::1.127 ...

Comment: Please clarify which Ubuntu flavor you are actually using, if it's Ubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME, Kubuntu, etc… Also, please clarify what video card and drivers you are using. This sounds very much like a bug that is causing Xorg to crash, rather than you being "logged out."

Comment: What did you do at `Aug 18 08:32:49`? I see a bunch of `sudo`, `su` sessions during which, running as `root` you could easily have killed your own session.

Comment: Show us what is in the "other logs" around  `Aug 18 08:32:49`. The reason you are posting is that you can't figure it out on your own. I cannot trust "I couldn't find anything that stood out in these others". You can ignore `wtmp` (See `man wtmp`).